# Rspec test to render no layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I can test my controller to render a certain layout with

```
expect { get :index }.to render_template(layout: 'my_layout')
```

But how can I test the controller to render NO layout?

The following first expectation passes, **but be careful**: the second expectation also passes! (testing the same code)

```
expect { get :index }.to render_template(layout: false)
expect { get :index }.to render_template(layout: true)
```

In Nov 2008, @david-chelimsky said:

> One way I've handled this successfully is to integrate_views for this
>   one example (in its own group) and specify that html elements from the
>   layout are not present in the form. It's a brittle example, but it's
>   only one.

I dont want to check the rendered view, but I did not find any better solution so far.

Does someone has a good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not a pretty one liner (you can always add a helper method), I've found that you can do this:

```
get :index
@templates.keys.should include(nil)
```

I tested this and it only works when I set `layout false`. Based on the [implementation of assert_template](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template) it gathers some information in to instance variables. The relevant ones are `@templates` and `@layouts` - each is a hash keyed by a string corresponding with how many times it was rendered.

`@templates` will contain the template used for your action (e.g `"users/show"`) but `@layouts` will only list layouts. If no layout was used, it looks like `{nil=>1}`. This seems the only thing you can tap in to.

So maybe it might be nice to make a helper method or [custom matcher](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/custom-matchers) to do this.

Comment: Thanks for that, I went with the line `@layouts.keys.should == [nil]` for my code (for now). Maybe will circle back for a custom matcher once this problem comes up again :)

Comment: Glad you got something to work. Remember to mark this as the answer so future visitors know it worked!

Comment: Alas, not my question, otherwise I would :)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't even notice ha.

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late to read the answers. I will try that and will mark it then. Thanks Robin

Answer (score 4):

In my tests when there is no layout I just check if it is not loading "application" layout

```
expect { get :index }.to_not render_template(layout: "application")
```

Comment: If it loaded another template this would pass and be a false positive.

Comment: Like I said, it is just to check if it is not loading "application". If there is an answer that solve this in a correct way I will also adopt it :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this one liner

```
expect { get :index }.to render_template(layout: [])
```

Versions: Rspec = 3.4.0 , Rails ~> 4.2.5

Comment: This actually does not work (or creates false-positives might be more accurate). If you define your layout at the controller level - i.e. `layout 'whatever'` outside of any action method - and then only use `render layout: false` on any actions where you *don't* want a layout to be used (such as if you're using a modal), then this test will pass for all of your actions.